# Analyze every function I call

Tags: php, function

I want to analyze the result of each function that I call. If this result is a exception or is false then the script ends. I can do this manually, but it is a big waste of time to call a control function for each new function.

Can I configure PHP to set this error function automatically?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do, but you are aware of http://www.php.net/set_error_handler?

Comment: There's some similar things you could do. But, you really should give a bit more detail about why you would want to do such an odd thing. Are you debugging? There's better ways. Is this going to be a real part of an actual script? There's better ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the comments , will give you and idea of how to register callbacks .

[How do I catch a PHP Fatal Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-error)

Here are some steps I ll suggest :

a) register  register_shutdown_function or other callback functions to track your exceptiosn

b) Each function call Should throw an exception when there is error

c) call_back function catches the exception

d) echo custom  output

check my comment on above reference question

Answer (score 0):

You mean the call_user_func and call_user_func_array functions?

```
function error ($funcName, $funcParameter) {
    try {
        $params = func_get_args();
        unset($params[0]);
        call_user_func_array($funcName, $params) or exit ("Error !");
    }
    catch (exception $e) {
        exit ("Error !");
    }
}
```